# I cannot i reinstall libc-bin on 16.04 - how to fix that? Problem started after failed upgrade 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade

This PC (Dell Optiplex 755) is running Ubuntu 16.04. A week ago, I tried to upgrade to 18.04, but it failed with the "`Aborting. Restoring Original state`" message. Ever since then, Software Updater has failed, with errors like `E: Internal Error, No file name for libc-bin:amd64`. (Several other packages updated successfully.) It all worked perfectly before the upgrade attempt. 
My most recent attempt to fix things went as follows:

```
$ apt-get download libc-bin
$ sudo dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb /
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for libc-bin:amd64
~$
```

I also tried "`sudo dpkg --configure -a`" based on other threads here. That also errors:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Bus error (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 135
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
~$
```

My goal is not to upgrade to 18.04, but just to get 16.04 working again.

```
OptiPlex-755:~$ apt-cache policy libc-bin:amd64 libc6:i386
libc-bin:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu10
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu10
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libc6:i386:
  Installed: 2.23-0ubuntu10
  Candidate: 2.23-0ubuntu10
  Version table:
 *** 2.23-0ubuntu10 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.23-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages

OptiPlex-755:~$ dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu
libuuid1:i386, libc6:i386, libsystemd0:i386, libpng12-0:i386, libglib2.0-0:i386, libncurses5:i386, libusb-1.0-0:i386, libjson-c2:i386, libgcrypt20:i386, libcomerr2:i386, libgcc1:i386, libpcre3:i386, libselinux1:i386, libtinfo5:i386, libgpg-error0:i386, zlib1g:i386, libexpat1:i386, libdbus-1-3:i386, libudev1:i386, libssl1.0.0:i386, libbsd0:i386, libcap2:i386, libwrap0:i386, libkeyutils1:i386, liblzma5:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu

OptiPlex-755:~$ grep -r 86 /etc/ld.so.conf.d
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu.conf:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
OptiPlex-755:~$ 

OptiPlex-755:~$ sudo ldconfig --verbose 
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
    libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu:
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Comment: Please use normal Markdown syntax, do not insert "html" tags. Please add output of `apt-cache policy libc-bin:amd64 libc6:i386` and `dpkg -S /lib/i386-linux-gnu` into the body of the question by clicking [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1116814/edit).  Also add output of `grep -r 86 /etc/ld.so.conf.d` to the question, get output of `sudo ldconfig --verbose` and upload it to pastebin.

Comment: @N0rbert I agree with your thinking: it has to be something to do with multiarch - maybe version mismatch between i386 and amd64 packages or the like?

Comment: I have edited (all) those outputs into the question. The last one provokes a "System Error, Report Problem?" to pop up! That last output is (also) in https://pastebin.com/5DSQggvs

Comment: Well, I decided to restore my from my clone of it. It worked in terms of fixing  Software Updater et al. During restore there were "short read" errors as well as orphaned inodes. As I understand things (not well), these should not be possible since GParted does fsck before copies, and, the clone backup partition was never used after GParted copied to it. I think 1) this disk is starting to have surface problems or other hw problems, and 2) that caused corruption, and 3) the upgrade just exercised it hard enough to reveal  problems. Many thanx to all for their efforts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

[How to get software updates working in 16.04? It broke after a failed upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116738/988544)

```
apt-get download libc-bin
sudo dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb /
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./libc-bin*.deb
```