# apt not working: installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, dpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Environment?

- Windows Subsystem for Linux.
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
- apt 1.6.11 (amd64)

#### What's wrong?

`apt upgrade` and `apt autoremove` not working.
`apt upgrade` gives the following message

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gtk-update-icon-cache libegl-mesa0 libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dev libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa
  libglx-mesa0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libmspack0 linux-libc-dev mesa-common-dev
15 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/12.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 4096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt autoremove` gives the following message

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`apt update` and `apt autoclean` seem to be working correctly.

#### Reproduce?

I have no idea what caused the error... Also, I do not think I have done any dangerous operation to non-user files recently. I have googled the error messages I got, but fruitless.
Anyone any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148715/how-to-fix-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-error) especially [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510887/344926)

Comment: Ever get more information about what caused this?

Comment: @Ramón No, I failed to find the cause... I just reinstalled the WSL at last, which was less painful than reinstalling a real Linux system...

Answer (score 15):

Interestingly enough, when I tried what Eric Gazoni did when [his slapd failed](https://www.adimian.com/blog/2014/10/how-to-fix-a-broken-ubuntu-package-installation-here-slapd/), of course `dpkg` didn't want me to forcibly remove vital organs of Ubuntu ;) ... But  after stubbornly executing through his instructions, replacing `slapd` by `libc-bin`, and afterwards moving `/tmp/libc-bin.*` back to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`, it repaired itself!

So, essentially this did the trick, although it is possible that not every command is necessary:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin
sudo dpkg --purge libc-bin
sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin
sudo mv /tmp/libc-bin.* /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Comment: Just `sudo apt install libc-bin` did the trick - **problem solved**. Thanks! P.S. Removing the package didn't work - for each I got an error `"this is an essential package; it should not be removed"`.

Comment: I was able to follow the first 4 steps posted by MrExquisite to solve this. sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin sudo dpkg --purge libc-bin sudo apt install libc-bin I am running 18.04LTS on WSL2 and was getting an error doing my usual apt-get upgrade. Thank you sir!

Comment: I had to use `--force-depends` instead of `--force-remove-reinstreq`, but this worked for me for a similar problem for `mime-support` - thank you!

Answer (score 10):

A slightly less invasive fix:

```
for PROBDIR in "" "/usr" "/usr/local"; do find "${PROBDIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -type f -ls; done;
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4760

Comment: Thanks so much, none of the other solutions worked, but this did.

Comment: This command simply finds files and makes no changes.  It is impossible for it to fix anything.

Comment: @DanLocks It's been a while since I tried this; I know it's not supposed to make any changes, but (based on the Github discussion), it seems like the filesystem ends up in a weird state which is fixed by accessing file metadata

Comment: This actually worked, I can't believe it.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 to fix a coredump

```
for PROBDIR in "" "/usr" "/usr/local"; do find "${PROBDIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" -type f -ls; done;
sudo apt install libc-bin -y
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.* /tmp/
sudo apt install libc-bin -y
```

Comment: This fixed it for me! Tried everything else. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Nothing else worked! Finally I tried his steps and voila! Back on track again

[How to get software updates working in 16.04? It broke after a failed upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/1116738/988544)

```
apt-get download libc-bin
sudo dpkg -x libc-bin*.deb /
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ./libc-bin*.deb
```

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me, but this did the job. I'm using a Debian WSL

Comment: Only this worked for me with WSL Ubuntu 23.04 lunar.