# 20.04 apt install upgrade is not working

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

**Environment?**

Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Ubuntu 20.04

**What's wrong?**

apt upgrade is not working.

1.apt upgrade gives the following message

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  alsa-ucm-conf apt apt-utils curl gh isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common landscape-common libapt-pkg6.0 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpython3.9-minimal
  libpython3.9-stdlib libssl1.1 libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-libc-dev nodejs open-vm-tools openssl python3-distupgrade python3.9 python3.9-minimal systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-release-upgrader-core udev update-notifier-common
32 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 760 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Aborted (core dumped)
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Path `/usr/lib' given more than once
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot:
        libfakeroot-0.so -> libfakeroot-tcp.so
/usr/local/lib:
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:
Aborted (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--configure):
 installed libc-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 134
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

2."remove" gives the following message

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc-bin
dpkg: error processing package libc-bin (--remove):
 this is an essential package; it should not be removed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc-bin
```

**Reproduce?**

[enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160366/apt-not-working-installed-libc-bin-package-post-installation-script-subprocess)
I referred to the link above, but it is still not solved.

Comment: Did you run the rest of the commands? Purging it (the next command) should do the trick.

Comment: and when you get to the installation command, just go ahead and add `--reinstall` for good measure: `sudo apt install --reinstall libc-bin`